# Disabling coordinate lines in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, scatter3d

I am trying to disable the black coordinate lines that appear in plotly.

[image: Scatter3d]

I still want the stock tickers to appear as text in hover.

I have already tried turning off hovermode but then my tickers don't appear. Is there any way to specifically turn off the black gridlines that appear when I hover over a point?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Plotly calls these [spikes](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-scene-xaxis-showspikes) or [spike lines](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#spike-lines), and they are set to appear by default for 3d scatter plots in Plotly. You can disable them with the following line:

```
fig.update_scenes(xaxis_showspikes=False, yaxis_showspikes=False, zaxis_showspikes=False)
```

For example:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
              color='species')
fig.update_scenes(xaxis_showspikes=False, yaxis_showspikes=False, zaxis_showspikes=False)
fig.show()
```

[image]